# Base case for Karatsuba Multiplication

Tags: algorithm, recursion, karatsuba

Just wondering why the base case for Karatsuba multiplication ( shown here: http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-karatsuba-multiplication-algorithm/) is chosen to be "N<= 10"? I found "N<= 4, 3, 2 ,1 " will not give me a correct result. Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karatsuba's algorithm will work correctly with any "sufficiently large" base case, where "sufficiently large" means "large enough that when it's divided into smaller subproblems, those subproblems are indeed smaller and produce the right answer." In that sense, there isn't "a" base case for Karatsuba as much as a general rule for what base cases might look like.

Honestly, the code you linked doesn't seem like it's a very reasonable implementation of the algorithm. It works with `long`s, which can already be multiplied in O(1) time on any reasonable system, and their base case is to stop when the numbers are less than 10<sup>10</sup>, meaning that with 64-bit numbers the recursion always terminates after a single step. A better implementation would likely use something like a `BigInteger` type that can support arbitrary-precision multiplication. At that point, choosing the optimal base case is a matter of performance tuning. Make the base case have a number of digits that's too small and the recursion to handle smaller numbers will take dramatically more time than just doing a naive multiply. Make the base too high and you'll start to see slowdown as cases better handled by the recursive step instead get spend using naive multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers with less than 10 digits can be multiplied natively (`x*y`), because the result will always fit in a signed 64-bit integer.

Using the `long` datatype doesn't make much sense though, since most number combinations that doesn't overflow, will just get evaluated natively. You would have to change to `BitInteger` or something similar, and use much larger numbers to get any gains from the algorithm.

As for why it is failing for lower limits of `N`, I am not sure. The algorithm have to be able to split both numbers into two similarly sized parts. I guess it ends up with zeros or negative numbers in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you included the source code in your post, you might well have gotten a to-the-point answer sooner.
If you used something like [`BigInteger.divideAndRemainder(dividend, divisor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#divideAndRemainder-java.math.BigInteger-) to "split" your numbers, you wouldn't run the risk to code something like

```
long d = y / m;
long c = y - (d * N);
```

(using a multiplier different from the divisor).
Note that the product of two `10` digit numbers doesn't always fit into Java's `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is recommended the size of the input should be equal to 1.So, if the input size is equal to 1. Then, you don't call the same function again, instead you just multiply them and return.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).